# Requests returns Too Many Requests status code

Tags: python, python-requests

The goal is to return `resp.text` for the account page

When you run this function you get the response code `429` that indicates too Many Requests were made.

even when running the script with proxychains
`proxychains python3 file.py`  it returns the same status code

file.py

```
import requests

def g3t_usr(acc):
    """ Surf to account page """
    resp = requests.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/{acc}/')

    if resp.status_code == 200:
        return resp.text
    else:
        print (resp.status_code)
    
    return resp.text 
 
acc="<some_random_user>"
g3t_usr(acc)
```

Does Instagram check for requests made by python requests and flags them

Comment: how `proxychains` works? Normally you could set proxy server in `requests.get(...proxies=...)`. I don't know how works `proxychans` and I can't say if `requests` uses it.  Besides, `requests` always send header `User-Agent: python/...` so it is easy to recognize that it is not real web browser but script/bot.

Comment: I always set my User-Agent and Origin when using requests.  It will give you better chances of not being flagged as a bot.

Comment: Looking at their robots.txt they could potentially block requests since they disallow all bots for user agents not explicitly specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try Specifying the „User-Agent“ in the header to make your request more „authentic“ like this: `requests.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/{acc}/', headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.4; Mobile; rv:41.0) Gecko/41.0 Firefox/41.0"})`

At my side, it worked and I got Status Code 200.

Wish you luck!